# Custom kernel boot options are lost on kernel update

Tags: boot, grub2, kernel

I need to add some custom boot options to grub (namely video=VGA-1:1366x768@6 to manage a 2nd monitor). Unfortunately this option is lost everytime a new kernel is installed. Is there a way to set an option so that the kernel update postinst applies to each entry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your custom kernel option for grub in file "/etc/default/grub" in line "GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT".

Answer (score 0):

It was quite easy actually : you can set

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash i915.alpha_support=1 video=VGA-1:1366x768@60"
```

in /etc/default/grub.